# Speed up Python Request from csv list

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

New to Python as in the below is my first attempt. What I have is a csv file listing client job numbers. I am doing 3 api calls to our (third party) work management system. 1 get the actual Job Number, 2 get the Job Stage and 3 get the Job Status(below). I have a vb.net app that pulls these results all apart mixes them with other data and add them to MYSQL data for reporting on a Ruby dashboard etc. The Grunt work wit the API calls was being done in excel vba as I could just do it all in the one place. The API call was slow, very slow so went looking at a way to hurry this along and Python popped up. Sorted the below as well as calling it from .net but it is still slow. All three calls take about 5 minutes in total. We are only looking at some 60 to 70 job numbers. The first call for the job number does bring a large json file through but unfortunately not the data I require in the 2nd and third calls so I cannot speed it up by eliminating 2 and 3.

As I have just jumped into Python head first I cannot easily see a solution. I have been looking at the multi-threading, multiprocessing posts but are all asked by people who have half a clue and I'm just not there yet.

Any help much appreciated.

```py
import requests
import csv


with open("C:\\******.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    jobs = []
    Stages = []
    outfile = open("C:\\*********another****.csv", "w")
    for row in readCSV:
        job = row[0]
        url = (
            "https:/********.com/api/v1.0/companies/**/jobs/"
            + job
            + "?columns=Status"
        )
        auth_token = "*******"

        payload = ""
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Bearer *********",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Host": "*****",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
        }

        response = requests.request(
            "GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers
        )
        Stage = response.text

        print((job, Stage), file=outfile)

    outfile.close
```

Comment: your code only shows making one `GET` request. do all 3 requests need to happen sequentially? also as a side note you are looking for multi-threading not multi-processing because this is an I/O bound task

Comment: @aws_apprentice The code is doing one GET request per `job` read from the CSV file, so there are as many requests happening as there are rows in the CSV file.

Comment: Each of the three are very much the same with the Status and Stage calls being identical. The first call for job number gets pulled apart to get the data for the 2nd and third calls. There is a delay between 1 and 2 and 2 and 3 so other processing can be done on the resulting files. It's really just the time it takes for each individual request that  This was my first ever attempt so with some advice and guidance on this one I hope to be able to nail the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you multiprocessing for getting the jobs.

The idea is to refactor getting the jobs from your CSV into one generator function, then the function that accesses the API into another.

(Since you're evidently on Windows, you'll need to use a `main()` function and an `if main` guard with `multiprocessing`.)

```py
import requests
import csv
import multiprocessing

sess = requests.Session()

headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Bearer *********",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Host": "*****",
}


def read_jobs():
    with open("C:\\******.csv") as csvfile:
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=","):
            yield row[0]


def get_job_status(job):
    url = (
        "https:/********.com/api/v1.0/companies/**/jobs/"
        + job
        + "?columns=Status"
    )
    response = requests.request(
        method="GET", url=url, headers=headers
    )
    print("Got job ", job)
    return (job, response.text)


def main():
    with open("C:\\*********another****.csv", "w") as outfile:
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            for result in pool.imap_unordered(
                get_job_status, read_jobs()
            ):
                print(result, file=outfile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks AKX that definitely added some pace to things and gives me an opportunity to build a bit on knowledge. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing depends on cores number. In your case threads is what you need.The simplest interface to threading is ThreadPool. E.g.:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

threads_count = 10
pool = ThreadPool(threads_count)

def do_job(url)
    return requests.get(url)

urls = ['url1', 'url2']

pool.map(do_job, urls)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```